# Is there an example of an inconsistent linear system with more variables than equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I believe that is impossible because there would always be free variables. Does anyone know if that is correct?

Comment: $x+y+z=1$ and $x+y+z=2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Take, for instance, the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y+z=0\\x+y+z=1.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Your solution applies 0 and 1 where 21 minutes earlier lulu had 1 and 2 hence you made significant progress.

Comment: @WlodAA lulu didn’t post an answer, though. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @amd "*ephemeral*" -- and so is coronavirus and life.

Comment: @WlodAA Do you think that this question shouldn't get an answer?

Comment: JCS, it was good that you've posted a simple and adequate answer. I am a bit into musing.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is linear algebra.

The expressions that contain the variables can be translated into vectors. If the vectors span a space of dimension less than the number of equations you can indeed have no solutions. Otherwise there is a solution.

Comment: U'r shooting at a housefly from a cannon.

Comment: No, I'm shooting a dust bunny with a rubber band

Comment: Cannons may shoot with rubber bands (I am not saying that cannons are efficient this way).